# Count the number of cells that are full

Tags: excel, vba

How would I count the number of cells that are full and get a return number

For example: Range("A4"), then count the number of cells that are under this that have text and return the count. Must stop when hits a cell with no text.

```
L = CountA("A4").End(xlDown)
```

Comment: What have *you* tried? `=COUNTA(...)` formula can do this, no frills.

Comment: What do you mean I tryed lastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A4").End(xlUp).Row but only wanna count down from a4 until there is nothing below i dont want it to count everything in A\

Comment: L = CountA("A4").End(xlDown) would somthing like this work

Comment: See my answer below. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EDIT: As per comments, this is the proper code:

**Simple `End(xlDown)` approach**

```
Sub GetCellCount()
    With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1") 'Modify as necessary.
        Set HeadC = .Range("A4")
        CellCt = HeadC.End(xlDown).Row - HeadC.Row
        MsgBox CellCt
    End With
End Sub
```

Result:

[image]

Let us know if this helps.

EDIT2: Not satisfied with the above, as the simple `End(xlDown)` approach may pose potential problems in the future. Other approaches below.

**Checking for empty cells approach**

```
Sub GetCellCountv2()
    With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1") 'Modify as necessary.
        CellCt = 0
        Set HeadC = .Range("A4") 'Modify as necessary.
        For Iter = HeadC.Row + 1 To .Rows.Count
            If Not IsEmpty(.Cells(Iter, HeadC.Column)) Then
                CellCt = CellCt + 1
            Else
                Exit For
            End If
        Next Iter
        MsgBox CellCt
    End With
End Sub
```

**Checking length of string approach**

```
Sub GetCellCountv3()
    With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1") 'Modify as necessary.
        CellCt = 0
        Set HeadC = .Range("A4") 'Modify as necessary.
        For Iter = HeadC.Row + 1 To .Rows.Count
            If Len(.Cells(Iter, HeadC.Column).Value) > 0 Then
                CellCt = CellCt + 1
            Else
                Exit For
            End If
        Next Iter
        MsgBox CellCt
    End With
End Sub
```

Hopefully this can solve a couple of potential issues with the request.

Comment: Its Giving me 23     With ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet 'Modify as necessary.
        LRow = .Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
        CellCt = LRow - 4 'Because you started from A4.
        MsgBox CellCt
    End With

Comment: No need to include the whole code in the comment. Where does your data end?

Comment: What i have is The header is A4 like you have then there is Content below that like you have I need it to just count that content. Example is Hearer is 4 lets say there is content up to 12 then there is a empty cell where it needs to end. there is more content after that empty cell that i dont want it count

Comment: Err. You are much welcome, good sir. :) Thanks as well for accepting the answer.

Comment: @DjCovey: Added two more samples in any case you encounter problems with the first code.